# Sed command works on Linux, but not on OS X

Tags: linux, macos, sed

I am using this sed command on Linux, to patch one file, and it works fine:

```
sed -i -r "s/(\tpublic function __call.*)/\1\n\t\treturn null;/" rb.php
```

But when I try this command on OS X, I am getting an error:

```
sed: 1: "s/(\tpublic function __ ...": \1 not defined in the RE
```

So, can anybody help me to make command that will work both on Linux and OS X?

By the way, I tried command like:

```
sed -i '' -r "s/(\tpublic function __call.*)/\1\n\t\treturn null;/" rb.php
```

but it doesn't work on Linux.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For the Mac OS X sed, use `-E` instead of `-r` to get EREs. Additionally, the GNU extensions aren't there, so you'll need literal characters instead of the `\t` and `\n` metacharacters.

Or just install GNU sed, of course.

Answer (score 1):

`(` is standard for perl, not for sed. You should use `\(` instead. Mac OS X does not use GNU sed.

Comment: `-r` is a flag for extended regex. so we don't need to escape `(`

Comment: `-r` is not documented in [Apple's sed man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sed.1.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think adding `-E` will make it work for both.

Comment: Necessary but not sufficient, I'm afraid.