# Converting timestamp from PST to UTC

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I need to convert the given datetime from PST to UTC, i gone through multiple forum examples but everywhere it mentioned about converting the server datetime. So could someone help me on this.

I will be getting arguments for my script in the format of yyyymmddhh (eg:2015101004 - it will be pdt), so now i need to convert it into UTC with the same format.

So for 2015101010 (PDT) I need the output as (2015101017) UTC. Could someone through some lights here.

Note: I am trying this in linux bash shell

Thanks.

Comment: Should the status of Daylight Saving Time (DST) be inferred from the date itself? If so, please update the question to include this information -- possibly with two examples: one with DST active and one with DST inactive. As it is written now, it is difficult to understand whether you will only work with PDT or whether you'll also be dealing with PST.

Comment: @Chrono, Yes i need to deal with both PST and PDT. Could you please recommend someway to handle both the timezones.

Answer (score 1):

You'd first need to normalize your datetime to a format recognizable by the GNU date utility. After that, you can further normalize it to an RFC 3339 timestamp, which includes timezone info. With that timezone info, GNU date will allow you to convert the time in that timezone to UTC with the `-u` option. Here's a script that does all that:

```
# Convert the "yyyymmddhh" string in argument $1 to "yyyy-mm-dd hh:00" and
# pass the result to 'date --rfc-3339=seconds' to normalize the date.
# The date is interpreted in the timezone specified by the value that
# the "TZ" environment variable was at first invocation of the script.
#
# Example 1: 2015-12-10 10:00 PST (UTC-0800)
#    $ env TZ='America/Los_Angeles' ./utcdate 2015121010
#    2015121018
#
# Example 2: 2015-10-10 10:00 PDT (UTC-0700; PST with DST in effect)
#    $ env TZ='America/Los_Angeles' ./utcdate 2015101010
#    2015101017

# Raw YYYYMMDDHH converted to YYYY-MM-DD HH:00.
convldt="$(echo "$1" | awk '
$1 ~ /^[0-9]{10}/
{
    year = substr($0, 1, 4)
    mon = substr($0, 5, 2)
    day = substr($0, 7, 2)
    hour = substr($0, 9, 2)
    printf("%s-%s-%s %s:00\n", year, mon, day, hour)
    exit
}
{ print "errorfmt" ; exit 1 }
')"
if test x"$convldt" = xerrorfmt ; then
    echo "note: Format must be YYYYMMDDHH." >&2
    exit 1
fi

# The converted time is then normalized to include a timezone.
normldt="$(env TZ="$TZ" date -d "$convldt" --rfc-3339=seconds || echo error)"
test x"$normldt" = xerror && exit 2

# Convert to UTC.    
date -u -d "$normldt" +'%Y%m%d%H'
```

Then you have a generalized script that will work for any timezone, and you just need to set `TZ` on the command line as noted in the script's first comment block. The script will take care of the rest, exiting when an error is encountered. `sed -r` could have been used in place of `awk` using a much more compact syntax (`-r` enables POSIX EREs, which are what `awk` uses for its regex syntax; `sed` defaults to POSIX BREs):

```
convldt="$(echo "$1" | sed -r 's/([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/\1-\2-\3 \4:00/')"
```

I used `awk` mostly because it's easier for me to read. `sed` would have worked just as well, though I'm honestly not sure how I would have handled the datetime format error as I did using `awk`. `sed` just doesn't seem like the right tool when error handling is desired.

If you plan to use this on OS X and not just Linux, [the `date` bits would need to be altered](https://superuser.com/a/356899/135137). Additionally, [`sed -r` would instead be `sed -E`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7914021/539810).

Comment: For some reason i am getting the format error, [$ env TZ='America/Los_Angeles' ./d 2015101000
errorfmt
note: Format must be YYYYMMDDHH.]  when i tried printing convldt i noticed a new line character so tried removing that but it didn't help. Any idea what's going wrong here.  [$ env TZ='America/Los_Angeles' ./d 2015101000
2015101000 errorfmt
date: invalid date `2015101000\nerrorfmt']

Comment: You likely don't have GNU awk (`gawk`) installed, or it isn't your default `awk` interpreter. I just updated it for compatibility with `mawk`, which is likely the trouble.